# Вставка видео на сайт

Tags: веб-программирование, аудио, видео

Какова очередность действий при вставке своего видеофильма на свой сайт html и его просмотра?

Answer (score 3):

Выбираете себе видеоплеер, соответствующий требованиям, и вставляете на сайт, используя [**swfobject.**](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

*В качестве хороших вариантов бесплатных видеоплееров могу порекомендовать [**flowplayer**](http://flowplayer.org/) и [**jwplayer.**](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)*

В некоторых случаях *(если, например, не нужны контролы для видео или видео используется как элемент дизайна)*, то можно написать свой `swf` файл, который будет проигрывать видео стандартными средствами `Flash`, или *(в случае, если вы являетесь поклонником современных, но не везде доступных технологий)*, то средствами `HTML5`.

---

Ну а если вообще не хочется долго думать, то можно залить видео, например, на `youtube.com` и вставить флеш-объект через `swfobject`.